# Create new column from existing Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I am having a Dataframe and trying to create a new column from existing columns based on following condition.

Group data by column named  **event_type** 
Only filter those rows where column  **source**  has value  **train**  and call it **X**.
Values for new column are **X.sum** / **X.length**

Here is input Dataframe

```
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------+------+
|   id|   event_type|  location|fault_severity|source|
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------+------+
| 6597|event_type 11|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 8011|event_type 15|location 1|             0| train|
| 2597|event_type 15|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 5022|event_type 15|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 5022|event_type 11|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 6852|event_type 11|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 6852|event_type 15|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 5611|event_type 15|location 1|            -1|  test|
|14838|event_type 15|location 1|            -1|  test|
|14838|event_type 11|location 1|            -1|  test|
| 2588|event_type 15|location 1|             0| train|
| 2588|event_type 11|location 1|             0| train|
+-----+-------------+----------+--------------+------+
```

and i want following output.

```
 +--------------+------------+-----------+
 |              | event_type | PercTrain |
 +--------------+------------+-----------+
 |event_type 11 |   7888     | 0.388945  |
 |event_type 35 |   6615     | 0.407105  |
 |event_type 34 |   5927     | 0.406783  |
 |event_type 15 |   4395     | 0.392264  |
 |event_type 20 |   1458     | 0.382030  |
 +--------------+------------+-----------+
```

I have tried this code but this throws error

```
    EventSet.withColumn("z" , when($"source" === "train" , sum($"source") / length($"source"))).groupBy("fault_severity").count().show()
```

Here EventSet is input dataframe

Python code that gives desired output is

```
event_type_unq['PercTrain'] = event_type.pivot_table(values='source',index='event_type',aggfunc=lambda x: sum(x=='train')/float(len(x)))
```

Comment: X is the column value 'train' as you define but how it gives X.sum and X.length? Are you mean X.sum is the total count of the source value with 'train'? and X.length means the total count of the column?

Comment: @Lamanus I updated question please read last part.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to obtain the percentage of train values. So, here is my code,

```
val df2 = df.select($"event_type", $"source").groupBy($"event_type").pivot($"source").agg(count($"source")).withColumn("PercTrain", $"train" / ($"train" + $"test")).show
```

and gives the result as follows:

```
+-------------+----+-----+------------------+
|   event_type|test|train|         PercTrain|
+-------------+----+-----+------------------+
|event_type 11|   4|    1|               0.2|
|event_type 15|   5|    2|0.2857142857142857|
+-------------+----+-----+------------------+
```

Hope to be helpful.